# Blazor: "Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined"

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I am working a project with Blazor Framework. But, I had a problem. I want to update, when click checkbox. I had "Check" column in my database. When I click checkbox; If "Check == false", it is working and successfully. But, if "Check == true" and I click it; I take is this error:

> "System.InvalidOperationException: TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'parentNode' of undefined    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InvokeRenderCompletedCallsAfterUpdateDisplayTask(Task
> updateDisplayTask, Int32[] updatedComponents)"

Code:

```
if (Check == false)
{
    UpdateObje.HP = true;
    await Http.SendJsonAsync(HttpMethod.Put, "/api/Project/" + ID, UpdateObje);

    Project = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Projects[]>("/api/Project/");
    ProjectList = Project.Where(A => A.ID!= "0").ToList();
    OtherList = Project.Where(A => A.ID!= "0" && A.HP == true).ToList();
}

if (Check == true)
{
    UpdateObje.HP = false;
    await Http.SendJsonAsync(HttpMethod.Put, "/api/Project/" + ID, UpdateObje);

    Project = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Projects[]>("/api/Project/");
    ProjectList = Project.Where(A => A.ID!= "0").ToList();
    OtherList = Project.Where(A => A.ID!= "0" && A.HP == true).ToList();
}
```

When I take this error; my project is frozen but my database updated. I check with debugging but it takes successfully but I still have taken this error. What can I do?

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript in this project that might be changing the dom?

Comment: Yes, I had a JavaScript. But, this not change the dom.